# Shorter code for an If statement testing a variety of matches

Tags: conditional

How can I shorten these two `If` expressions into one

```
 variable="hello";
 If[variable=="hi", Print["hi there"]];
 If[variable=="hello", Print["hi there"]];
```

Longhand shortening:

```
 If[variable=="hello" || variable=="hi", Print["hi there"]];
```

to something like this:

```
 If[variable=={"hello","hi"}, Print["hi there"]];
```

Comment: Use `MemberQ[{"hello","hi"}, variable]`

Comment: And if you have to test against many different conditions, `Which` and `Switch` might be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
If[MemberQ[{"hi", "hello"}, variable], Print["hi there"]];
```

Should do the trick. List membership is usually the same as equivalence, and it should always be the same with strings.

Since it was mentioned in the comments, `StringMatchQ` would work quite well if your strings had more in common with each other. As it stands, it's just a binary pattern:

```
If[StringMatchQ["hello", "hello" | "hi"], Print["hi there"]];
```

Which works, but clearly isn't leveraging the full potential of a pattern matching functions. It'd be more applicable if you were matching to a much larger set of fairly similar strings.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. I was just looking at StringMatchQ, but I think MemberQ is a safer choice.

Comment: @TomMozden It's perfectly applicable here, but it seems like a waste to me for this problem. If you were comparing a much larger set of very similar strings, I think it'd be much more useful.

Comment: I have a list of 10+ items in my real program. I just mentioned two here to illustrate what was needed.

Comment: If they have sufficient similarity to be amenable to pattern matching, go for it. I'd think it's more applicable when you have enough items that you start resorting to combinatorics to count them though.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it with `MathchQ` and `Alternative` ( `]` ).

```
If[MatchQ[#, "hello" | "hi"], "hi there", "no match"] & /@ {"hello", "hi", "g'day"}
```

> `{"hi there", "hi there", "no match"}`